# What does it mean "phoniness"

Tags: word-usage

I just came across a tweet in which the word "phoniness" appears.

> the corruption, the deep sense of entitlement, the phoniness, the lack of real accomplishments

After some searches and some thoughts, considering that in the context that word could be related to some phone problem, I cannot be able to decipher it.

Please, describe what "phoninness" means in that context and whether at level of a joke it is related with some phone problem.

Comment: Insincerity. Lack of authenticity.

Comment: Look up "phony".

Comment: (It should be spelled "phoniness".)

Comment: Say, if someone were to post a question about something they knew the answer to, simply so that they could imply things about a third party, that would be "phony".

Answer (score 1):

First:

> - What does it means?

What does it **mean**?

The **/way/quality/manner/substance/** of someone who is ***phony***, which is present in most dictionaries:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phony

It means **"being fake, false."**